Run NullAway analyzer but encounter assertion error on NullAway initialization
I'm attempting to detect null pointer exceptions in a Java file using NullAway. However, NullAway cannot be runned due to an assertion error related to its initialization:
java.lang.AssertionError: com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneInjector$ProvisionException: Failed to initialize com.uber.nullaway.NullAway
        at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneAnalyzer.lambda$scansPlugins$0(ErrorProneAnalyzer.java:85)
        at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:181)
        at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneAnalyzer.finished(ErrorProneAnalyzer.java:156)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.MultiTaskListener.finished(MultiTaskListener.java:133)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1436)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1383)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:963)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:319)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:178)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:64)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:50)
Caused by: com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneInjector$ProvisionException: Failed to initialize com.uber.nullaway.NullAway
        at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneInjector.getInstance(ErrorProneInjector.java:92)
        at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneInjector.getInstance(ErrorProneInjector.java:65)
        at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ScannerSupplierImpl.instantiateChecker(ScannerSupplierImpl.java:66)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1024)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
        at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ScannerSupplierImpl.get(ScannerSupplierImpl.java:74)
        at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ScannerSupplierImpl.get(ScannerSupplierImpl.java:37)
        at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneAnalyzer.lambda$scansPlugins$0(ErrorProneAnalyzer.java:80)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:74)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
        at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneInjector.getInstance(ErrorProneInjector.java:90)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/checkerframework/nullaway/dataflow/cfg/node/NodeVisitor
        at com.uber.nullaway.handlers.Handlers.buildDefault(Handlers.java:67)
        at com.uber.nullaway.NullAway.<init>(NullAway.java:291)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.checkerframework.nullaway.dataflow.cfg.node.NodeVisitor
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        ... 28 more

Below is the script I used to execute NullAway. I followed the instructions from Error Prone and made some modifications in accordance with the NullAway documentation:
EP_VERSION=2.23.0
DATAFLOW_VERSION=3.39.0-eisop1
NULLAWAY_VERSION=0.10.15
JSPECIFY_VERSION=1.0.0

# check if downloaded, if not, download
error_prone_core_jar=error_prone_core-${EP_VERSION?}-with-dependencies.jar
dataflow_errorprone_jar=dataflow-errorprone-${DATAFLOW_VERSION?}.jar
nullaway_jar=nullaway-${NULLAWAY_VERSION?}.jar
jspecify_jar=jspecify-${JSPECIFY_VERSION?}.jar

if [ ! -f $error_prone_core_jar ]; then
    wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_core/${EP_VERSION?}/$error_prone_core_jar
fi
if [ ! -f $dataflow_errorprone_jar ]; then
    wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/github/eisop/dataflow-errorprone/${DATAFLOW_VERSION?}/$dataflow_errorprone_jar
fi
if [ ! -f $nullaway_jar ]; then
    wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/uber/nullaway/nullaway/${NULLAWAY_VERSION?}/$nullaway_jar
fi
if [ ! -f $jspecify_jar ]; then
    wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jspecify/jspecify/${JSPECIFY_VERSION?}/$jspecify_jar
fi

echo "Jar files downloaded"

javac \
  -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -XDcompilePolicy=simple \
  -cp .:$jspecify_jar \
  -processorpath $error_prone_core_jar:$nullaway_jar:$dataflow_errorprone_jar \
  '-Xplugin:ErrorProne -XepOpt:NullAway:AnnotatedPackages=com.uber -Xep:CollectionIncompatibleType:ERROR' \
  com/uber/mylib/ShortSet.java

echo "Compilation finished"

The source of "com/uber/mylib/ShortSet.java" is identical to the example provided by NullAway:
package com.uber.mylib;

import org.jspecify.annotations.Nullable;

/**
 * A sample class.
 */
public class ShortSet {

  static void log(Object x) {
    System.out.println(x.toString());
  }

  static void foo() {
    log(null);
  }
}

And my java version is:
$ java --version
openjdk 21.0.4 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04, mixed mode, sharing)

I am seeking assistance in understanding why NullAway is unable to initialize successfully. Thank you for your help!
NullAway can be runned successfully and detect the NPE in code.

You need to add
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>dataflow-nullaway</artifactId>
</dependency>

to your classpath or processorpath (I'm not sure which).
EDIT according to Ziao Li should be added to processorpath.

Thanks a lot! It works by adding to processorpath
